# Request to Facebook Graph API returns no data

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send a get request to Facebook graph API from a node js app. I hardcoded a user access token I got from the graph api explorer and used the app id and app secret from the dashboard to log the user in.
I have already logged the user in through facebook with passport.

Below is the code that sends the request

```js
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

 console.log("position 3");

 const options = {
     method: 'GET',
     uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=id,name',
     port:8000,
     qs: {
       access_token: user_access_token
     }
 };

    http.request(options,function(res){
     console.log("position 4");
        //res.json(res);
    })
});
```

The problem is, I get a 200 status code but no data. The console displays "position 3" but doesn't display "position 4". Can anyone please explain why is the request returning no data. I have seen a similar post but the problem isn't exactly the same as mine.

Comment: `port:8000` - assume this is a parameter pertaining to the request you are making, so it would actually make the request to `https://graph.facebook.com:8000/…`? Why? What makes you think the API would use that port?

Comment: I had left it out before and I would get a ECONNREFUSED error!

Answer (score 0):

Try with those options:

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?fields=id,name&access_token=' + user_access_token
};
```

Btw, keep in mind that user tokens are only valid for 2 hours and you can extend them to 60 days max.